# Why is my ScheduledExecutorService schedule not working

Tags: java, timertask, scheduledexecutorservice

I'm trying to schedule a task with the ScheduledExecutorService (in the scheduleMatch method). I see that the constructor of my Task class is called, but the Run method is never called. I also have a scheduleAtFixedRate and that one is working fine, it is been called every 30 seconds. Please see my code below, Am I missing something or why is this code not working:

MatchTaskScheduler

```
public class MatchTaskScheduler {

private final ScheduledExecutorService fScheduler;
private final ScheduledExecutorService matchScheduler;
private static final int NUM_THREADS = 1;
private static final int MATCH_SCHEDULER_NUM_THREADS = 10;
private static MatchTaskScheduler taskScheduler;


private MatchTaskScheduler(){       
    fScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(NUM_THREADS);   
    matchScheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(MATCH_SCHEDULER_NUM_THREADS);   
}

public static MatchTaskScheduler getInstance() {
    if(taskScheduler == null) {
        taskScheduler = new MatchTaskScheduler();
    }
    return taskScheduler;
}

public void scheduleMatchScheduler() {
    //This one is working correct
    fScheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ScheduleMatchTask(), 150, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

public void scheduleMatch(Match match) {
    Validate.notNull(match, "match of plublic method scheduleMatch shouldn't be null");

    Date scheduledDate = match.getDate();
    Logger.info(this, "Schedule match at: " + scheduledDate);
    if (null == scheduledDate || !scheduledDate.after(new Date())) {
        Logger.error(this, "Match with matchId: " + match.getId() + " isn\'t scheduled because date is in the past");
        return;
    }

    long startTimeInSeconds = (scheduledDate.getTime() / 1000) - (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    Logger.info(this, "Current date: " + sdf.format(new Date()));
    Logger.info(this, "Match with matchId: " + match.getId() + " scheduled for: " + sdf.format(scheduledDate));
    try {
        matchScheduler.schedule(new MatchTask(match), startTimeInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
    } catch (RejectedExecutionException e) {
        Logger.error(this, e.toString(), e);
    } catch (NullPointerException e1) {
        Logger.error(this, e1.toString(), e1);
    }
    Logger.info(this, "Match will start in " + startTimeInSeconds + " seconds.");
}
}
```

MatchTask

```
public class MatchTask extends TimerTask {

private Match match;

public MatchTask(Match match) {
    Validate.notNull(match, "match of plublic constructor MatchTask shouldn't be null");
    Logger.info(this, "Set match for Runnable + " + match.getId());
    this.match = match;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("Match ID: " + match.getId() + ", current time: " + new Date().getSeconds());
}
}
```

This is what I see in the logfile and on 08:33:00 there is nothing in the logfile. The next thing is on 8:33:04 when the scheduleAtFixedRate is called.

```
[21/10/14 08:32:34:631 CEST]  INFO task.MatchTaskScheduler: Schedule match at: 2014-10-21 08:33:00.0
[21/10/14 08:32:34:631 CEST]  INFO task.MatchTaskScheduler: Current date: 21-10-2014 08:32:34
[21/10/14 08:32:34:632 CEST]  INFO task.MatchTaskScheduler: Match with matchId: 002 scheduled for: 21-10-2014 08:33:00
[21/10/14 08:32:34:632 CEST]  INFO task.MatchTask: Set match for Runnable + 002
[21/10/14 08:32:34:632 CEST]  INFO task.MatchTaskScheduler: Match will start in 26 seconds.
```

---

Solved: The problem was the System.out.println when I replaced that one with a Logger.info it was working fine.

Comment: Your Match class doesn't output anything to the log file. It writes to System.out.

Comment: Most stupid question ever, you are right the System.out was the problem. I replaced it by a Logger and now it is working fine! Thanks @JBNizet Sorry for your time!